# Run report programmatically with url using C#

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, reporting-services-2012

i have a Url of report that is on the SSRS server, the Url contains:

```
http://<**ServerAdress**>/<**ServerName**>/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?<**reportPath**>&<**report_Parameters**>
```

programmatically (using C#) i want to execute the url without opening the browser.
when i use  the *ReportExecutionService* i have to define the parameters manually (using `ParameterValue[]`...)  i dont know how to invoke them from the url.
so, is there a way i can execute the report with the url without opening the browser?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30095445/save-ssrs-report-as-pdf-in-c-sharp-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically call a URL using C#:

```
    public static async Task<bool> CallUrl(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept",
                "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1");

            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Example of calling that method:

```
        var result = CallUrl("http://www.bbc.co.uk");
        result.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine(result.Result);
```

This should run your report, without opening the browser.

Comment: thanks for the answer.
the status is OK, but the report doesnt run on background.
maybe i miss something?

Comment: Make sure the URL you are passing through to the CallUrl() method is correct.

Comment: The url is fine, can it be the SSRS?
maybe to tun a report from the ssrs i need something more?